# Cannot execute ld : error 126

Tags: fedora, compiling, error-handling, ld

I have `f30` installed 3 weeks and I keep seeing this error when I try to compile `C++` of maybe `fortran` code.

It is an error connected to `ld` : `error: ld returned 126 exit status`

I've tried to look into it and so far I have no explanation.

What I can share is that `ld` resides in `/usr/bin` which is a soft link from `/etc/alternatives`.

```
[astamato@pcen35240 ~]$ ls -al /usr/bin/ld*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 Apr 26 04:27 /usr/bin/ld -> /etc/alternatives/ld
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   13536 Aug 11 11:27 /usr/bin/ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    5441 Jun  6 13:55 /usr/bin/ldd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3853632 Mar  6 11:00 /usr/bin/ld.gold
```

When I try to execute `ld` by it self (so not having it called from another program or installation script), I get the following

```
[astamato@pcen35240 talys]$ /usr/bin/ld
bash: /usr/bin/ld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

[astamato@pcen35240 talys]$ sudo /usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld: cannot execute binary file
```

Then I searched the original `/etc/alternatives` location, but it's again a soft link

```
[astamato@pcen35240 talys]$ ls -al /etc/alternatives/ld*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Apr 26 04:27 /etc/alternatives/ld -> /usr/bin/ld.bfd
```

Surprisingly enough, the link is to a `ld.bfd` file which is in `/usr/bin`.

I tried to find the version of `ld.bfd` but it seems that it cannot be executed

```
[astamato@pcen35240 talys]$ /usr/bin/ld.bfd --version
bash: /usr/bin/ld.bfd: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
[astamato@pcen35240 talys]$ sudo /usr/bin/ld.bfd --version
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: /usr/bin/ld.bfd: cannot execute binary file
```

Any idea on how to understand what is wrong and solve the issue?

**EDIT**

After @steeldriver 's suggestion I report the following outputs

```
$ file -L /usr/bin/ld.bfd
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d88173c7f8919542e59738a8c5b626f6ed81d7d8, stripped, too many notes (256)
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: You have presumably managed to overwrite the native `ld.bfd` with one for a different architecture - what are the outputs of `file -L /usr/bin/ld.bfd` and `uname -m` ?

Comment: @steeldriver : Thank you very much for your comment! Please see my updated question.

Comment: Thanks... but unfortunately it seems to be more subtle than simply an incompatible architecture. Let's hope someone else has a better idea.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! I hope so, because I really need it and the next option is to reinstall fedora...

Comment: @I think I solved it!!! I reinstalled `binutils` using `sudo yum reinstall binutils` and it seems it is working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why it happened or if it could be fixed otherwise or if it will have an effect somewhere else but I just reinstalled `binutils` and it seems it solved it.

So just type

```
sudo yum reinstall binutils
```

and it should be ok.